# Query the target device for installed PCI devices on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, devices, video, camera, pci

Is there a way to query the target device for installed PCI devices on ubuntu.
I use VideoCapture Card and 8 cameras. Every time /dev/video* changes but I would like to assign a camera to specific /dev/video*.

Comment: Probably the right way to handle this is by creating predictable symlinks through udev rules - see for example [Assign webcam to a specific /dev/video#](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715333/assign-webcam-to-a-specific-dev-video/715417)

Comment: I cannot reach the idvendor, idprouct and serial number of cameras that plugged in CaptureCard.